# typescript + node How to get instanse from methods?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

After server rebuild, compiller creates instanse in included api controller here:

**NewController.ts**

```js
import express        = require("express");
import INew           = require("../interface/INew");
import NewRepository  = require("../repositories/NewRepository");

class NewController {
    private _newRepository: INew;
    constructor() {
        this._newRepository = new NewRepository();
        this._newRepository.findById(5);
    }

    retrieve(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void {
        try {
            console.log('-----------retrieve--------------------');
            this._newRepository.findById(2);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }

}

Object.seal(NewController);
export = NewController;
```

constructor works: i see console message:

> ```
> -------------NewRepository------------------
> 5 'RESULT'
> ```

**NewRepository.ts:**

```js
import INew     = require("../interface/INew");
import bluebird = require("bluebird");

class NewRepository implements INew {
    sd: string;

    constructor() {
        console.log('-------------NewRepository------------------');
    }

    findById(id: number): void {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log(id, 'RESULT');
        }, 3000);
    }
}

export = NewRepository;
```

**INew.ts**

```js
interface INew {
    findById: (id: number) => void;
    sd: string;
}

export = INew;
```

**Buut when i use controller's method 'retrieve', visit rout '/new' then i get error [TypeError: Cannot read property '_newRepository' of undefined] instead : 2 'RESULT'**

**Angular 2 helps me with routing:**

```js
.............
  getCarsRestful(): Promise<New[]> {
    console.log('-------------------------------');
    return this.http.get('api/new')
      .toPromise()
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
...................
```

**and execute backend:**
**NewRoutes.ts**

```js
import express       = require("express");
import NewController = require('../controllers/NewController');

  var router = express.Router();

  class NewRoutes {
    private _newController: NewController;

    constructor() {
      this._newController = new NewController()
    }

    get routes() {
      var controller = this._newController;
      router.get("/new", controller.retrieve);
      return router;
    }

  }


Object.seal(NewRoutes);
export = NewRoutes;
```

my created instanse '_newRepository' doesn't exist already, why? i get console log:

> ```
> -----------retrieve--------------------
> [TypeError: Cannot read property '_newRepository' of undefined]
> ```

Help please, how to make 'singltone' in ts
i don't want to create it in every controller's method, though, that works:

```js
.................
retrieve(req: express.Request, res: express.Response): void {
    try {
        var _newRepository: INew;
        _newRepository = new NewRepository();
        _newRepository.findById(2);
.............
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly set **this** in router config:

```
 router.get("/new", controller.retrieve.bind(controller));
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it is really helped